# Mask page overflow without scroll top

Tags: html, jquery, css, height, overflow

I'm working on my website Ajax page transition. In order that my new page displays top I need to 'reset' the scroll and so I set my old page to `height: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden` just before loading the new one.

However when I do that my old page scroll top. Do you know how can I avoid that?

```js
$("#stop-button").click(function() {
  $(".container").toggleClass("stop")
})
```

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* can't be set on: 
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  */
}

.content {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width;
  100%
}

.un {
  background-color: #9d7070
}

.deux {
  background-color: #709d8d
}

.trois {
  background-color: #919d70
}

#stop-button {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff
}

.stop {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content un"></div>
  <div class="content deux"></div>
  <div class="content trois"></div>
</div>
<div id="stop-button">Stop !</div>
```

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/Jeanlat/pen/MWmGJNY)

Comment: thanks for the link to the codepen, but please always include the relevant code in the question so that people don't have to go off-site to help you. Regarding the question - what exactly is the issue? You want the page to scrollback to the top when someone clicks an external link?

Comment: Thanks ! I forget to say that I'm working on **Ajax** page transition. I would like that before transition, my "old" content container to be set on 100vh high, then to play transition and finally to display the new content. If I don't do that new content will be display with old scroll height. 
My question is about the first step, how can I set my container to `height: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden` without it scroll top.. Is that clearer ?